# Evaluating the $A \land A \land A$ in the Chern-Simons action

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebra, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I am trying to evaluate $A \land A \land A$, but I am a bit confused on how exactly to do it and produce the usual notation used in physics. I am trying to use the definition of the wedge product of Lie algebra valued forms given here [Lie algebra-valued differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra-valued_differential_form), but I am not sure how to proceed. Any input is very much appreciated.

Comment: The CS action has ${\rm tr}(A\wedge A \wedge A)$ and the trace simplifies things greatly. You only need the structure funtions and the quadratic Casimir in the representation in which the $A$'s live.

Comment: @mike stone The trace does simplify things, but I would like to see how would one go from $tr(A \wedge A \wedge A)$ to $\epsilon ^{\mu \nu \rho} tr(A_{\mu} A_{\nu} A_{\rho})$ which is how it is usually introduced in physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help:

Consider a lie-lagebra valued form  $A=A_\mu^a \lambda_a dx^\mu$ then
$$
{\rm tr}(A^3)= {\rm tr} \{\lambda_a\lambda_b \lambda_c\} A^a_\alpha A^b_\beta A^c_\gamma dx^\alpha \wedge dx^\beta \wedge dx^\gamma\\
{\rm tr} \{\lambda_a\lambda_b \lambda_c\} A^a_\alpha A^b_\beta A^c_\gamma \epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma} dx^1\wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3\\
\frac 12 {\rm tr} \{\lambda_a[\lambda_b, \lambda_c]\} A^a_\alpha A^b_\beta A^c_\gamma \epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma} dx^1\wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3.
$$

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks